# Magento2 Admin Backend Category Brand Sort Order changes like A...B....C..D...E..F First A Second B Like that

Tags: magento2, admin, category, sequence

Magento2 Admin Backend Category Brand Sort Order changes like A...B....C..D...E..F  First A Second B Like that

Give ME Answer

Emizentech
ShopByBrand
plugin i will be used

> Emizentech\ShopByBrand\view\adminhtml\layout\emizentech_shopbybrand_items_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Emizentech. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Emizentech\ShopByBrand\Block\Adminhtml\Items" name="adminhtml.block.promo.quote.grid.container">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="adminhtml.block.promo.quote.grid" as="grid">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">emizentech_shopbybrand_items_grid</argument>
                        <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Emizentech\ShopByBrand\Model\ResourceModel\Items\Collection</argument>
                        <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">sort_order</argument>
                        <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">ASC</argument>
                        <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" as="grid.columnSet" name="adminhtml.promo.quote.grid.columnSet">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="path" xsi:type="string">emizentech_shopbybrand/*/edit</item>
                                <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="id" xsi:type="string">getId</item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="id">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="name">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="sort_order">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sort Order</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">sort_order</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="featured">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Featured</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">featured</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                                <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Emizentech\ShopByBrand\Model\Status"/>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> emizentech_shopbybrand_items_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Emizentech. All rights reserved.
 */
-->

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <block class="Emizentech\ShopByBrand\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Edit\Tabs" name="emizentech_shopbybrand_items_edit_tabs">
                <block class="Emizentech\ShopByBrand\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Edit\Tab\Main" name="emizentech_shopbybrand_items_edit_tab_main"/>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">main_section</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">emizentech_shopbybrand_items_edit_tab_main</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Emizentech\ShopByBrand\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Edit" name="shopbybrand_items_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thank You
Your Faithfully,
Mehul Kanjariya

[image]

Comment: share your code